# Move folder from root of Hard Disk to Current Directory

Tags: bash, shell, permissions, directory, filenames

I'm trying to figure out how to move a folder that sits in the root of my disk (what do you call that, home?) to a subdirectory.  I am not cd'd to the root (again not sure of the terminology).

When I say root, here is what I think it means.

[image]

So what would I call "Macintosh" the name of my disk when talking in terms of the file system and UNIX?

So, for example, I'm currently cd'd to `/user/[myprofilename]/code` and I want to move a file that lives at the root into the `code` folder.  Or maybe I'm not cd'd to the `code` folder and I am in some unrelated folder but still want to move that `themes` folder to within that `code` folder.

In other words, if I'm not cd'd into the same directory as the `themes` folder (root) how would one easily move that from wherever you cd'd to currently?

Example I tried to do something like this but you it doesn't work:

```
$ mv ../themes .
```

I also tried:

```
$ mv ~/themes .
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I just tried `/themes .` and it says permission denied... but that seems to want to rename `/themes` to `./themes`, at least that's what the message says?  I don't want to rename the folder I want to move it so I still appear to be going about it the wrong way?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The root directory is `/`. The `themes` directory in the root directory is `/themes`. A path that starts with `/` is called an *[absolute path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths)*; it starts from the root directory. A path that doesn't start with `/` is called a *relative path*; it starts from the current directory of the program where you use it. For example, a bare file name with no directory indication is a relative path. `dir/subdir/somefile` is also a relative path.

`~` is an abbreviation for your home directory. That's the directory where you can put what you want. Each user account has its own home directory. Your [home directory](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51280/where-do-i-find-my-user-folder-in-the-os-x-folder-hierarchy) something like `/Users/bob`. Since `~` is an abbreviation which is expanded by the shell `~/something` is an absolute path — it's `/Users/bob/something`.

Users don't have the permission to modify file outside of their home directory. Use [sudo](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/sudo.8.html) to run a command with elevated privileges, including the privilege to modify files anywhere.

```
sudo mv /themes .
```

Comment: I know what an absolute path is, I just didn't know UNIX treated it the same and it's still called the same in Unix and OS X.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Gilles. This is all I was asking for.  Clearing this up.  It's not as clear as you think coming from a non OS X / Unix environment (this is why I got the hell out of .NET) at first even when reading a ton of stuff all over online.  It's quite overwelming at first learning UNIX, even basic commands have alot of options.

Comment: for anyone reading this, sudo mv /themes . worked for me.